# asp.net website deploymnet on client

Tags: asp.net

I have completed building a website for a client.Now i want to deploy this website on the server, So that client can access the website like a normal website. what is the best way to do it.
I am using C#,asp.net 3.5, Ms Access.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to protect the source code as well?

**YES**

- Install the [Web Deployment Project](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=0aa30ae8-c73b-4bdd-bb1b-fe697256c459&DisplayLang=en) for Visual Studio (there is on for VS2008 and other for VS2010)
- Add that project to your solution
- Add a Web Setup project to your solution
- Tell the Web Setup project that to load the Deploy project as source
- Build the Solution
- You will have in the Web Setup folder a `setup.exe` and `Website.msi` ready to be installed in any client machine (client needs to have IIS)

**NO**

- Add a Web Setup project to your solution
- Tell the Web Setup project that to load the Web Site project as source
- Build the Solution
- You will have in the Web Setup folder a `setup.exe` and `Website.msi` ready to be installed in any client machine (client needs to have IIS)

[image]

---

All 3 projects, **Web Site** + **Deploy project** + **Setup Project**

[image]

Comment: @balexandre thanks any good link so i can follow it step by step.

Comment: I gave you the step by step ... just follow each point. What do you need exactly?

Comment: added an image to help you understanding the `Solution`

Comment: i have mywebsite running here locally on iis,i have added the websetup to the project as you shown in the last image to the solution explore,now i am confuse with how should i make the setup file and then test it first locally, then install it on the server for the client.from first step till the end of deployment. Thanks alot

Comment: **1st** stop running your site locally from Visual Studio. **2nd** add the `WebSetup` project to your solution, `right click` on it and choose your Web Site (or Deploy project). **3rd** `right click` in the solution and build. **4th** go to the WebSetup folder and into `/bin/release/` you have the setup files there. Install from there in your local machine! it will create a Virtual Directory in your IIS and will run from there, test it. **5th** You can send the 2 files to your client or use `Click-Once` deploy and give the URL to your client.

Comment: **5th You can send the 2 files to your client or use Click-Once deploy and give the URL to your client** what are the names of these file to be send to the client?

Comment: it's all files inside your Web Setup Project `output directory`